# Correct usage of 'majority' in a sentence

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement

Did I have them all grammatically correct? Please correct me if I'm wrong in any of these cases:

1. The majority of our population are Buddhists.
2. The majority of our population belongs to Buddhists.
3. The majority of our population is demanding justice.
4. The majority of our employees support the new plans.
5. The majority of today's women are aware of their rights.

Comment: (2') Buddhists make up the majority of our population. // I'd probably rephrase (3) too, as it personifies 'majority' and seems clumsy. But (1), (4) and (5) are fine.

Comment: You can also say "The Majority of our population is Buddhist." Depends on whether you want to use Buddhist as a noun or an adjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1), (4), and (5) are fine.

(3) is also fine, though it may appear clumsy to some.

An example of a sentence very similar to (3) can be found in [this book](https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=01VKAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA1340&lpg=PA1340&dq=a%20majority%20of%20our%20population%20consumes%20inadequate&source=bl&ots=_cLnTDkytD&sig=ACfU3U1n2RePJZnduIDyzfNZ9YZn_zR_uw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiT04nU9bPqAhURcCsKHQfvCocQ6AEwBXoECAoQAQ)

> The majority of our six percent of the world's population consumes one-half of the world's nonrenewable resources.

The "our" refers to the US, where the population of the US is six percent of the world's population. Hence, it can be rewritten as

> The majority of our population consumes one-half of the world's nonrenewable resources.

Statement (2) is an interesting one. I'm guessing that the intended meaning is that most of the population are Buddhists. In that case, the way that it is expressed would be wrong, as we would normally say somebody belongs to Buddhism, or to Christianity, or to some other religion, rather than "belongs to Buddhists", "belongs to Christians", etc. For example:

> Hindus constitute roughly 11 percent, and the rest belong to Buddhism and Christianity.

(from [this book](https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=wMz0ZKWrQ8YC&pg=PT269&lpg=PT269&dq=%22belong%20to%20buddhism%22&source=bl&ots=Ob0j_Tn9lI&sig=ACfU3U2r2twaPd-D7w5VYexs_0cNNIToZg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjl-tSE-LPqAhWrIbcAHeDBBGgQ6AEwCXoECAgQAQ)).

However, as pointed out by Jason Bassford in a comment below, statement (2) can be interpreted differently, with the meaning that Buddhists own most of the population (assuming humans can own other humans), and so most of them belong to Buddhists. This would then be grammatically correct but false.

Comment: I'm not sure that 'The majority of our population consumes one-half of the world's nonrenewable resources' sounds idiomatic. Even 'Most Americans consume one-half of the world's nonrenewable resources' is suspect. There has to be an actual persentage / fraction.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Googling for "majority of our population" results in other examples, e.g., in https://www.census.gov/library/stories/2019/12/2020-census-count-guides-funding-of-new-roads-and-bridges.html, has "The majority of our population is living in .." ; maybe it's more idiomatic in US English. I agree that  'Most Americans consume ..' is suspect, but for a different reason. I think "majority of our population" can be treated as a group, and therefore singular, whereas "Most Americans consume .." almosts sounds like each of those insatiable Americans by themselves consumes one half of ..

Comment: There is nothing ungrammatical or wrong about (2). It's just not a true statement. What it means is *Buddhists own the majority of our population.* It's completely grammatical. But what it means is something different than how you're interpreting it.

Comment: Thanks @JasonBassford , I edited the answer.